# Reading in a CSV text file for Decision Tree Learning in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, classification, decision-tree

Using import csv and import sys

How would I go about reading in a list of comma separated values and attributes so that I can determine the information gain of said attributes to generate a decision tree model? This is given a csv and a text file of attributes with their potential values.

An example from Russel and Norvig:

restaurant.csv:

```
Will-Wait,Alternative,Bar,Fri/Sat,Hungry,Patrons,Price,Rain,Reservation,Type,Estimated-Wait
Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Some,$$$,No,Yes,French,0-10
No,Yes,No,No,Yes,Full,$,No,No,Thai,30-60
Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Some,$,No,No,Burger,0-10
Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Full,$,No,No,Thai,10-30
No,Yes,No,Yes,No,Full,$$$,No,Yes,French,>60
Yes,No,Yes,No,Yes,Some,$$,Yes,Yes,Italian,0-10
No,No,Yes,No,No,None,$,Yes,No,Burger,0-10
Yes,No,No,No,Yes,Some,$$,Yes,Yes,Thai,0-10
No,No,Yes,Yes,No,Full,$,Yes,No,Burger,>60
No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Full,$$$,No,Yes,Italian,10-30
No,No,No,No,No,None,$,No,No,Thai,0-10
Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Full,$,No,No,Burger,30-60
```

restaurant-attributes.txt:

```
Will-Wait,Yes,No
Alternative,Yes,No
Bar,No,Yes
Fri/Sat,No,Yes
Hungry,Yes,No
Patrons,Some,Full,None
Price,$$$,$,$$
Rain,No,Yes
Reservation,Yes,No
Type,French,Thai,Burger,Italian
Estimated-Wait,0-10,30-60,10-30,>60
```

Using something like this...

```
restaurantSet = []

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as csvfile:
    restaurant = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for val in restaurant:
        x = [q for q in val]
        restaurantSet.append(x)
```

what would be the best method to make a list of each attribute and that attributes values; i.e. patrons would be a list of [Some, Full, Some, Full, Full, Some, None, Some, Full, Full, None, Full].

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to read data from a file? from stdin?

Comment: This is a good question. Are you looking to generate a decision tree based on your instincts? Or are you looking to use machine learning to build optimal trees?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Pandas you can simply use

```
data = pd.read_csv("restaurant.csv", sep=",")
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good start to an answer.